# JQuery UI draggable along with pointer

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Am building a page which has draggable panel. In which it has a standard grid.when I scroll down the grid the  draggable panel is moving along with the pointer.
""

$("#drag").draggable();

I also used the below options but not useful
• helper: clone;
• position: absolute; helper
• scroll: true 
• refreshPositions: true

Please suggest me how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am 90% sure this is what you meant, if not, just comment.

The following uses the `scroll()` function to detect scroll and then it uses the `scrollTop()` to detect the amount scrolled.  Then that value, after being subtracted from the previous amount scrolled, will then be applied to `$("#drag")`'s top css attribute.

```js
$("#drag").draggable();

previous = 0;
$(window).scroll(function () {
 currentDelta = $(window).scrollTop() - previous;
 previous = $(window).scrollTop();
 $("#drag").css("top", (Number($("#drag").css("top").slice(0,-2))) + currentDelta + "px");
});
```

```css
#drag {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background-color:red;
}

/* makes the page longer */
body {
  height:1200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="drag"></div>
```